# How to make sub engines with SOLR & NUTCH?

Tags: solr, nutch

greetings all
I am making a search engine with a template like google
that contains news sub engine & images sub engine & videos sub engine
and I was wondering about how to make the sub engines with SOLR & NUTCH 
I am really new to them, and don't have any idea how to do so, so please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no concept of sub-engines in NUTCH/SOLR... you may use different plug-ins to index your different data in different fields. You can develop a different web front end for the different data type/fields.
Hope this helps

Comment: thanks a lot, but can you please give me a little more details or references ?

Comment: As for references the best remains the Nutch Wiki.

Comment: Regarding details, basically you should use the relevant nutch plugins (or create them) to analyse the documents, store the indexes in different fields. As a 2nd step you can use SOLR to create pages which will query only the fields relevant to your sub-engine. Hope this is more clear.

Comment: thanks a lot for the good feedback, if someone has more info please help.